# Teamviewer 12 GUI doesn't start after upgrade to 17.10

Tags: 17.10, teamviewer

I recently updated my PC from Zesty to Artful, and it seems that Teamviewer doesnt work anymore.

I tried to run it from the shell, but it doesn't start.

When I check the logs i only see this:

```
(): KeepAlive-Connection initialized with ID 531816778 (IP: 169.54.83.56), SendQueue 0 (0 Bytes), SendIndex 0, AckIndex 0, RemoteSessionID 10
2017/12/02 12:03:37.484  1320 4150184768 S!  KeepAliveSession::SendCompleteQueue(): SendQueue: 0 (0 Bytes), RemoteSession 10 (ClientID 531816778), Time: 0 ms
2017/12/02 12:03:37.583  1320 4141792064 S   TVRouterClock Schedule next request in 0 seconds
2017/12/02 12:03:37.584  1320 4141792064 S   TVRouterClock Schedule next request in 0 seconds
2017/12/02 12:03:37.692  1320 4150184768 S   TVRouterClock: received router time: 20171202T170337.635155
2017/12/02 12:03:37.693  1320 4150184768 S   TVRouterClock Schedule next request in 43200 seconds
2017/12/02 12:03:38.000  1320 4018834240 S!! RemoteSessionManager::ClearAllRemoteSessions(): Timeout, 0 RemoteSessions left after 2 seconds
2017/12/02 12:03:38.000  1320 4141792064 S   RetryHandle::HandleRetry: Trying Resend to 13 failed with error SecureNetwork: Could not connect retrying (2 retries remaining) Bcmd: CC=19 CT=3
2017/12/02 12:03:38.017  1320 4141792064 S   RetryHandle::HandleRetry: Trying Resend to 13 failed with error SecureNetwork: Could not connect retrying (2 retries remaining) Bcmd: CC=19 CT=1
2017/12/02 12:03:38.020  1320 4150184768 S!! SecureNetworkConnectionMap: UpdateConnection: Update non existing ID in map, Errorcode=11
2017/12/02 12:03:38.125  1320 4141792064 S   TVRouterClock Schedule next request in 0 seconds
2017/12/02 12:03:38.126  1320 4141792064 S!  KeepAliveSessionOutgoing::ConnectEndedHandler(): KeepAliveConnection with server19604.teamviewer.com ended
2017/12/02 12:03:50.019  1320 4141792064 S   SecureNetworkConnection::SendCallbackHandler(): [ remoteID: 13 connection: 1821302207 remoteConnection: 0 ], Error: RCommand (Timeout)
2017/12/02 12:03:50.019  1320 4141792064 S   SecureNetworkConnection::SendCallbackHandler(): [ remoteID: 13 connection: 1821302207 remoteConnection: 0 ] Resetting connection due to error RCommand (Timeout)
2017/12/02 12:03:50.019  1320 4141792064 S   RetryHandle::HandleRetry: Trying Resend to 13 failed with error SecureNetwork: Could not connect retrying (1 retries remaining) Bcmd: CC=19 CT=3
2017/12/02 12:03:50.020  1320 4141792064 S   RetryHandle::HandleRetry: Trying Resend to 13 failed with error SecureNetwork: Could not connect Not retrying (0 retries would remain) Bcmd: CC=19 CT=3
2017/12/02 12:03:50.020  1320 4141792064 S!! AsyncMessaging::UnregisterAtAsyncMessageProvider(): Unregister failed: Could not connect
2017/12/02 12:03:50.021  1320 4141792064 S   RetryHandle::HandleRetry: Trying Resend to 13 failed with error SecureNetwork: Could not connect retrying (1 retries remaining) Bcmd: CC=19 CT=1
2017/12/02 12:03:50.021  1320 4141792064 S   RetryHandle::HandleRetry: Trying Resend to 13 failed with error SecureNetwork: Could not connect Not retrying (0 retries would remain) Bcmd: CC=19 CT=1
2017/12/02 12:03:50.022  1320 4141792064 S!  ConfigurationControllerImpl::HandleProviderRegistrationResponseInternal(): register failed with error SecureNetwork:3
2017/12/02 12:03:50.022  1320 4141792064 S   SecureNetworkConnection::Handle_ServerHello(): [ remoteID: 13 connection: 1821302207 remoteConnection: 0 ] Error RCommand (Timeout)"
```

It seems it can't connect to a kind of server, but I have no idea how to fix it.

Comment: It doesn's support Wayland desktop environment. Try running it under Gnome with Xorg and it will work

Comment: Under Gnome there seems to be a timing problem at the start of teamviewerd. If "https://askubuntu.com/questions/971025/teamviewer-connection-could-not-be-established-reason-unknown-error" happens to you, add a `sleep` value to the script as described there.

Comment: it doesnt work neither i already added it to that script

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works but i doesnt run under Wayland desktop enviroment , it works under Gnome